# Local variable in Ruby passed to Linux Terminal

Tags: ruby, linux

This probably isn't as hard as I'm making it, but how does one pass a local variable cleanly to the command line as part of a directory?

I'm concatenating similar text files (based off of a string) and storing them in a new text file that contains that same string.

- Assume I have a directory named class which contains a text file named after each student. Formatted as LastName_FM
- I also have a list of students' lastnames named students

For example:

```
for lastname in students
   'cat class/*'+lastname+'*.txt > /class/'+lastname+'_list.txt'
end
```

Theoretically, if I have files named:

- Smith_JM.txt
- Smith_TR.txt
- Smith_WE.txt
- 2Smith_WE.txt  (Different students with the same name.)

I would end up with a file named Smith_list.txt that would contain the contents of the four files.

Thanks for any pointers, I'm brand new to Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose the system command in [`backticks`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60) and interpolate the variable into the command because the backtick method supports interpolation.

Here's a contrived example that launches gedit:

```
local_var = "gedit"
`#{local_var}`       # interpolation syntax is #{...}
```

**EDIT:**  Here's another example that demonstrates interpolation within a block and writes the contents of `foo.txt` to `bar.txt`.  You could do something similar with a `for` loop, but that's not a common ruby idiom.

```
files = ['foo.txt']

files.each do |f|
  puts "#{f}"           # block variable interpolated within double quotes
  `cat #{f} > bar.txt`  # block variable interpolated within backticks
end
```

Comment: Hmmm, so it's acceptable to interpolate the iterator?

I tried:
    'cat class/*#{lastname}*.txt > class/#{lastname}_list.txt'

I'm showing an error at the space between cat and cmd. (unexpected tIDENTIFIED, expecting keyword_end

Comment: Make sure you are using backticks and not single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you can in the command do something along the lines of:

```
cd /mydir/subdir/subsubdir && cat class/*zoo*.txt > class/zoo_list.txt
```

Use back ticks as indicated in comments to run this.

or

you can do this in Ruby only using a combination of Dir.glob File.open and reading/writing.